# uncaught type error: type error, in external script

Tags: javascript, html, syntax-error, photo, object-detection

So Im attempting to use a a JavaScript photo taking application called photo-booth and also attempting to detect when a face enters the screen of the photobooth application and have it put out the coordinates of the face in the console.

But whenever I I seem to get it set up right I get a error that says "Uncaught TypeError: Type error" in the external script that is object_detect.js seen in the image below:

LINK TO IMAGE------> [Uncaught Type Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fFXxl.png)

Now this is what my javascript code looks like shown here: 
**(note: example is the div id of the photobooth)

```
 var video = $("#example").get(0);

            $(video).objectdetect("all", {scaleMin: 3, scaleFactor: 1.1, classifier: objectdetect.frontalface}, function(coords) {
                if (coords[0][1] > 80 && coords[0][1] < 170) {                          
                    //console.log(objectdetect.length);         
                        console.log ( coords[0]);

                }
            });
```

Here is the link to the object detect html example (it works if you host it locally): [object detect](https://github.com/mtschirs/js-objectdetect/blob/master/examples/example_sunglasses_jquery.htm)

Any ideas as to what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Go to the _Console_ tab to see more of the error, and a stacktrace.

Comment: I did goto the console and it traced it to the photo above!